# Как запустить скрипт?

Tags: windows, python, скрипт

Как запустить скрипт, написанный на python 2.6, в 7-ке через консоль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подойдёт любой из вариантов:

1. В контекстном меню скрипта выбрать "Открыть с помощью..." и в появившемся окне выбрать интерпретатор питона (`python.exe`). В этом случае можно ассоциировать `*.py` файлы с интерпретатором.
2. Открыть консоль и ввести что-то типа `путь_к_python.exe путь_к_скрипту`. Если путь к  `python` уже есть в переменной окружения `PATH`, то можно просто `python путь_к_скрипту`.

Comment: @eigenein Снова я тупыми вопросами), а как добавить  путь к питону в переменную patch?

Comment: @Tim http://www.oszone.net/6157/

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\путькпитону\python scriptname.py
```

?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "C:\Server\repositories\projects\python_examples\first\HelloWorld.py"